# Accessing one database from another

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, informatica

I have two databases where  one table in one database has around 6 million records and other table from other database has around 6 thousand records. I need to fetch all the matching records from the table with 6 million records.

Is there any way other than DB link?

Comment: Define "matching" - it is not a standard technical term.

Comment: same data in a column in both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this with Informatica... my preference is to extract the 6000 rows from db 1, load into a  table in a private schema on db 2 and with visibility of the table with 6M rows. That way when you run your query the join will help to optimise the source qualifier and everything will be gravy so long as you have correct indexes defined on the join condition fields

The alternate is to query the 6000 row table in your source qualifier and lookup the matching rows against the 6 million row table using a lookup transformation configured to return multiple rows for multiple matches. If you can either cache the 6M records without a sweat or handle 6000 queries to the db with little time hit then try this but multireturn lookup is a bit more finicky than stsndard lookup so I'd avoid as the next fella probably wont get it

Comment: What are your thoughts on having the 6000 row table be the lookup table? I imagine this would be lighter on the memory requirements, and the 6M rows need to read either way, soo... Is there a reason you do it exactly the other way around? The lookup of 6000 rows could easily be cached, I think.

Comment: Sure I'd rather query against a 6 million record table / cache 6000 times than query against a 6000 record table / cache 6 million times... assuming indices etc the actual cache size will get factored out so that the actual number of queries issued will carry the bulk overhead. If you read my full post you'll see that I'd prefer to do neither by getting all the data to live together in one db somehow which would enable a join in the db itself to reduce number of records read altogether (and you don't have to pull all 6 million records this way)